# Dependency Injection and Connection Factory

Tags: c#, ado.net, ninject

I am trying to use DI with Factory. What I have so far is:

Factory:

```
public interface IConnectionFactory
{
    IDbConnection Create();
}

public class DbConnectionFactory : IConnectionFactory
{
    private readonly DbProviderFactory _providerFactory;
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public DbConnectionFactory(string connectionString, string providerName)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
        _providerFactory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(providerName);
    }

    public IDbConnection Create()
    {
        var connection = _providerFactory.CreateConnection();
        if (connection != null)
            connection.ConnectionString = _connectionString;

        return connection;
    }
}

public class DbContext
{
    private readonly IDbConnection _connection;

    public DbContext(IConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
    {
        _connection = connectionFactory.Create();
    }

    public IDbCommand CreateCommand()
    {
        var cmd = _connection.CreateCommand();
        return cmd;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _connection.Dispose();
    }
}

public static class DbCommandExtensions
{
    public static IDbDataParameter CreateParameter(this IDbCommand command, string name, object value)
    {
        var parameter = command.CreateParameter();
        parameter.ParameterName = name;
        parameter.Value = value;

        return parameter;
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
public class AgentRepository : IAgentRepository
{
    private readonly DbContext _context;

    public AgentRepository(DbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public bool Exists(string input)
    {
        using (var command = _context.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.Connection.Open();
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.CommandText = @"";
            command.Parameters.Add(command.CreateParameter("@input", input));
            return (bool)command.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, in my client application I would like to pass connection string down to repository. Connection string will be created dynamically from other data source. I also would like to have service layer which pulls data from repository and passes DTO to the client. As DI container I am using Ninject. My question is how client should be implemented and how should configure Factory in Ninject?

-- EDIT 1
To move my project forward I implemented an anti pattern:

Service:

```
public AgentService(string connectionString)
{
    var connectionFactory = new DbConnectionFactory(connectionString, "System.Data.SqlClient");
    var context = new DbContext(connectionFactory);
    _agentRepository = new AgentRepository(context);
}
```

Client:

```
var connectionString = _systemService.GetConnectionString(ip);            
var agentService = new AgentService(connectionString);
var exists = agentService.Exists(input);
```

I know that this is not best practice but I wasn't able to implement it using DI. Please let me know how can I refactor this piece of code as I am going to implement the same for over 30 classes.

-- EDIT 2
I've did dome refactoring and end up with:

```
// Client:
var connectionString = _systemService.GetConnectionString(ip);
var dbConnectionFactory = new DbConnectionFactory(connectionString, "System.Data.SqlClient");
var agentService = new AgentService(dbConnectionFactory);

var exists = agentService.AgentExists(input);

// Service:
public class AgentService : IAgentService
{
    private readonly IAgentRepository _agentRepository;

    public AgentService(IDbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
    {
        var context = new DbContext(connectionFactory);
        _agentRepository = new AgentRepository(context);
    }

    public bool AgentExists(string input)
    {
        return _agentRepository.AgentExists(input);
    }
}

// Repository:
public class AgentRepository : IAgentRepository
{
    private readonly DbContext _context;

    public AgentRepository(DbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public bool AgentExists(string input)
    {
        using (var command = _context.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.Connection.Open();
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.CommandText = @"";
            command.Parameters.Add(command.CreateParameter("@param", input));
            return (bool)command.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    }
}

// Connection Factory:
public class DbConnectionFactory : IDbConnectionFactory
{
    private readonly DbProviderFactory _provider;
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public DbConnectionFactory(string connectionString, string providerName)
    {
        _provider = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(providerName);
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }


    public IDbConnection Create()
    {
        var connection = _provider.CreateConnection();
        if (connection != null)
            connection.ConnectionString = _connectionString;

        return connection;
    }
}

// DbContext:
public class DbContext
{
    private readonly IDbConnection _connection;

    public DbContext(IDbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
    {
        _connection = connectionFactory.Create();
    }

    public IDbCommand CreateCommand()
    {
        var cmd = _connection.CreateCommand();

        return cmd;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _connection.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I wonder if it would be possible to replace new operators in Service class with dependency injection. If it is possible how should it be configured using Ninject?

Comment: Sorry, but what is the question?

Comment: @OlegI Added my question at the end of the post. Let me know if anything else is not clear.